# How to select dropdowns in cypress with div tags

Tags: drop-down-menu, cypress

I'm getting this error while accessing the dropdown with select command in cypress.
cy.select() can only be called on a . Your subject is a: -- Sele...

Here's my code:
it('New user',() =>{

```
        cy.get(':nth-child(2) > .oxd-input-group > :nth-child(2) > .oxd-input').type('Admin')
        cy.get(':nth-child(3) > .oxd-input-group > :nth-child(2) > .oxd-input').type('admin123{enter}')
        //To hide sub menu
        cy.get('.oxd-main-menu-search > .oxd-icon-button').click()
        // To show sub menu
        cy.wait(2000)
        cy.get('.oxd-main-menu-search > .oxd-icon-button').click()

        /// for leave
        ///cy.get(':nth-child(3) > .oxd-main-menu-item > .oxd-text').click()
        
        cy.get(':nth-child(1) > .oxd-main-menu-item').click()
        cy.wait(2000)
        cy.get('.orangehrm-header-container > .oxd-button').click()

        ///To Add a user
        cy.get(':nth-child(1) > .oxd-input-group > :nth-child(2) > .oxd-select-wrapper > .oxd-select-text > .oxd-select-text-input').click().select('Admin')
```

here's the website html:
[html code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iZbac.png)
[the drop down , i'm trying to access](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j36A0.png)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When there are div's creating a dropdown you can't use `cy.select`, that command is only for HTML `<select>` control.

If you use `cy.click` instead, firstly to open the dropdown and secondly to chose the option you want by name.

It's basically the same as a user would do.

The test code is something like

```js
cy.get('[role="listbox"]).click()
cy.contains("Admin")
  .should('be.visible')
  .click()
```